# Unable to find QCARWrapper

Tags: android, eclipse, unity-game-engine, qcar-sdk

I've created a QCAR project in Unity which I can successfully run on Android from Unity. However, I'm encountering a problem exporting it to an Eclipse android project. I have followed the instructions from [here](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/Android-Integrating%20Unity%20With%20Eclipse.html) but when I try to run the app I get the following error in the logcat

```
01-19 16:20:42.521: D/dalvikvm(30361): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.my.app/lib/libQCARWrapper.so 0x4824dce8
01-19 16:20:42.521: I/dalvikvm(30361): Unable to dlopen(/data/data/com.my.app/lib/libQCARWrapper.so): Cannot load library: find_library[1188]:  2389 'libQCARWrapper.so' failed to load previously
01-19 16:20:42.521: E/Unity(30361): Unable to find QCARWrapper
```

The missing file is in my library project but not my Android project. I have tried putting it directly in my project and various build path combinations but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when integrating with Eclipse and is caused with a conflicting AndroidManifest.xml file especially if you are using an OBB splitter/APK Expansion pack. The trick is to
1) Take a backup of the Manifest file imported when you import Vuforia's Unity package.
2) Take a backup after the Google OBB Downloader package is added to the project. 
3) Merge these both files into one AndroidManifest.xml file ensuring that all activities realted to "UnityPlayerXXXXX.activity" and "QcarUnityPlayerXXXXXX.activity" are declared in the manifest.

and Voila !!!...