# Integrating Unity with Eclipse - How to follow the "official" tutorial's instructions?

Tags: android, eclipse, unity-game-engine

I have read all the documentation I found on how to integrate Unity3D projects targeted to Android into eclipse. The reason I want to do that is to be able to call the Unity3D Activity within my own "normal" Android application.

Well, I tried to follow the steps [listed on this tutorial](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/Android-Integrating%20Unity%20With%20Eclipse.html).
Using all the combinations I can imagine, I did the following:

1. I used the Unity Android project and built it (within the Unity
   IDE), then copied the `/Temp/StagingArea/` folder to another location.
2. I created a new Android project, using create from existing sources,
   setting the location of the `StagingArea` copy folder. This would be
   the Android Library Project. Check "is Library" on properties ->
   Android.
3. Again, I create an Android project, import the previusly created
   Android Library project and `classes.jar`.
4. I **move** the `asset` folder contents from the Library project to the
   "Activity" project. It has two subfolders, `bin` and `libs`.
5. I modify the generated Activity to extend `UnityPlayerActivity` and
   remove the setContent line of the onCreate method. Change the
   package to match the Unity Player bundle id.
6. Add the corresponding lines to manifest, basically those that are on
   the Library project.

So everything compiles without errors, and I can run the project, shows the splash screen, and then a black screen, playing the sounds of my Unity Scene correctly. The logcat reveals the following errors:

```
01-26 16:51:46.415: D/dalvikvm(2299): Trying to load lib /data/data/es.fundacionvf.unity.gps/lib/libQCARWrapper.so 0x40515a38
01-26 16:51:46.415: E/Unity(2299): Unable to find QCARWrapper
01-26 16:51:46.415: D/dalvikvm(2299): Trying to load lib /data/data/es.fundacionvf.unity.gps/lib/libQCARWrapper.so 0x40515a38
01-26 16:51:46.415: E/Unity(2299): Unable to find QCARWrapper
01-26 16:51:46.415: D/dalvikvm(2299): Trying to load lib /data/data/es.fundacionvf.unity.gps/lib/libQCARWrapper.so 0x40515a38
01-26 16:51:46.415: E/Unity(2299): Unable to find QCARWrapper
01-26 16:51:46.415: I/Unity(2299): StopQCAR
01-26 16:51:46.415: I/Unity(2299): UnityEngine.Debug:Internal_Log(Int32, String, Object)
01-26 16:51:46.415: I/Unity(2299): UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
01-26 16:51:46.415: I/Unity(2299): UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:print(Object)
01-26 16:51:46.415: I/Unity(2299): TrackerBehaviour:StopQCAR()
01-26 16:51:46.415: I/Unity(2299): TrackerBehaviour:OnApplicationPause(Boolean)
01-26 16:51:46.415: I/Unity(2299):  
01-26 16:51:46.415: I/Unity(2299): (Filename: /Applications/buildAgent/work/842f9557127e852/Runtime/Export/Generated/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 34)
01-26 16:51:46.425: D/dalvikvm(2299): Trying to load lib /data/data/es.fundacionvf.unity.gps/lib/libQCARWrapper.so 0x40515a38
01-26 16:51:46.425: E/Unity(2299): Unable to find QCARWrapper
01-26 16:51:46.425: I/Unity(2299): DllNotFoundException: QCARWrapper
01-26 16:51:46.425: I/Unity(2299):   at (wrapper managed-to-native) TrackerBehaviour:stopTracker ()
01-26 16:51:46.425: I/Unity(2299):   at TrackerBehaviour.StopQCAR () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
01-26 16:51:46.425: I/Unity(2299):   at TrackerBehaviour.OnApplicationPause (Boolean pause) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Just to mention... read these two SO questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749841/unity3d-integration-with-android/7884945#7884945) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645787/android-apk-size-difference-from-unity-directly-and-integrating-unity-in-eclipse). They seem to have succeded, so it is possible to achieve following those steps (or similar).

I also found useful [this topic on the Unity3D forum](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/71607-Integrating-Unity-and-Eclipse), which basically describes the same proccess in a clearer way.

Has anybody experienced this issue? Any suggestion or alternative?

Regards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For anyone stumbling across this, the integration of Unity3d into an android eclipse project was broken in the previous version (3.5)!

Using a newer version of Unity (successfully tested with 3.5.2) everything works fine again following [these steps](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/Android-Integrating%20Unity%20With%20Eclipse.html).

If you want to define your own activity or use Unity inside a fragment, you can use the UnityPlayer class directly. To do so you can have a look at **[UNITY_INSTALLATION]\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\androidplayer\src\com\unity3d\player** as mentioned in the [Unity Forum](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/71607-Integrating-Unity-and-Eclipse).

Or just try this code that worked for us:

```
    UnityPlayer mPlayer = new UnityPlayer(getActivity()); // Put your activity object here
    int glesMode = mPlayer.getSettings().getInt("gles_mode", 1);
    boolean trueColor8888 = false;
    mPlayer.init(glesMode, trueColor8888);

    // Get the view - e.g. to return from the fragment method onCreateView:
    View view = mPlayer.getView();
```

---

Update: The first link is not available on the unity3d support page anymore, but the forum entry contains all needed steps too!

Comment: It's quite better to get the latest ones rather than the old ones to use it with less flaws!

Comment: @sunadorer // the first link is broken.

Comment: @DavidDimalanta: Exactly. When I wrote this one year ago, 3.5.2 was the latest version. I am currently not working with Unity3d anymore and therefore can not say anything about a newer version.

Comment: @Youngjae: The second link to the forum includes all needed steps, too. The first link contained the official instruction. It seems they  completely removed it from the Unity page anymore. I can't tell if this means the Integration is not possible anymore in this way.

Comment: @sunadorer // Yes. I just want to clarify for readers of your valuable answer :)

Comment: I now took the time to update the answer to clarify that more. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing same thing. found that some more qcar related stuff is needed on top of unity project integration.
it's mainly linking Qcar libraries and modifying manifest activities. 
have a look here
https://ar.qualcomm.at/arforums/showthread.php?t=1243

However not helping to me much. still getting same error. a bit stuck with it.

Comment: I tried that as well, didn't work her either :(. Useful information, though.

Answer (score 0):

There is another page on SO asking this question. They claim to have obtained an answer on the qualcomm forums, different from the one above: [Unable to find QCARWrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929747/unable-to-find-qcarwrapper)